# Unambiguous IVP solutions under Lipschitz property

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-writing, lipschitz-functions, initial-value-problems

Show that the solution of the differential equation $$x'(t) = f(x(t))$$ with the initial condition $$x(0)=x_0$$ is unambiguous if f is Lipschitz continuous.

I have read the definition of Lipschitz continuous on wikipedia and I understand it but I don't know how to prove that the solution is unambiguous

Comment: Do you know the Grönwall lemma? How much did you understand of the proof of the Picard-Lindelöf theorem?

Comment: I had not seen that before thanks now I understand!